# How to Load Data into Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, load-time

I'm currently writing a web application that requires some data from the server to be stored in a Javascript object.  The amount of data that needs to be loaded is very small, probably around 1 KB.  I'm faced with the decision of how to load the data into the application.  Here are the two *obvious* (to me anyway) paths I could take:

1 - Using jQuery's document-ready function, I make an AJAX request to the server and store the response in the appropriate Javascript object.  It might look something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $.get('index.php?get=data', function(data) {
        myObj.addData(data);
    });
});
```

2 - The alternative would be to send the data along with the page during the initial page request.  In order to do that, I would have my server generate the data and output it in the markup between `<script>` tags.  Since my current project is in PHP, it would look something like this:

```
...
</div>
<script>
    window.myData = <?= json_encode($myData) ?>;
</script>
...
```

The jQuery document-ready function would later look for the global variable called `window.myData` and load it into the appropriate Javascript object like this:

```
$(function() {
    myObj.addData(window.myData);
});
```

---

Is there a preferred way of loading data into Javascript objects?  Although the amount of data being stored is relatively small, the AJAX call could result in a longer wait if the server's ping isn't great.  However, it would seem that AJAX calls are more popular when it comes to these things.  Is there a valid reason?

---

EDIT:  The data would very rarely be changed (maybe once a year).  Therefore, browser caching should not be much of an issue.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor No, I believe `json_encode` is the correct function.  Note that `$myData` is an associative array in PHP that should be converted to an array in Javascript.  Therefore, encoding it into JSON will provide the correct syntax that Javascript will understand.

Comment: I prefer option 1:window.myData = <?= json_encode($myData) ?>;

Mainly as you have the data on load rather then getting the data after on load. But that's if the data, is like you say, small.

Comment: json_encode is typically used server side to encode the request data into javascript object notation. jQuery will handle the decode after the request. json_decode will turn a json object into a php array which cannot be used directly by javascript without manually parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the $.getJSON method:

```
$.getJSON('/functions.php', { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $('body').append($('<div>', {
            text: element.name
        }));
    });
});
```

OR could use the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to loop through the data:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://example/functions.php', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('body').append($('<div>', {
                text: element.name
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about why this method is the better choice?  I don't see any advantage to loading the data in a separate request.

Comment: or if you are using jQuery.parseJSON - new in jQuery 1.4.1 so refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I'm still unclear about why this is the way to do it.  I know that option is there, but I would like to know **why** it is the better option, or **why** it is not.

Comment: This is the preferred method. Personally I load the data as raw text than use jQuery.parseJSON(response) after the request. I only do this because on occasion i do actually want the raw text of a response. How you manage what data is pulled per request is up to you, but this is how to handle the response as a javascript object. JSON = JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: @Hobbes, thanks for the input. Would you say this just a matter of convention?

Comment: Convention and ease of use. Once you get used to using json, you will wonder how you ever used ajax without it. Basically it converts php arrays/objects into javascript. Very convenient.